# Changing css class properties based on condition (*ngIf in angular 2)

Tags: css, angular, angular-ngselect

I want my css class to change based on condition. I'm trying to use this:

```
<div *ngIf="dropDownBg==='Active'">
<style type="text/css">
.ui-select-toggle{
    background: green !important;
  }
</style>

</div>


<div *ngIf="dropDownBg==='Suspended'">
<style type="text/css">
.ui-select-toggle{
    background: red !important;
  }
</style>

</div>

<div *ngIf="dropDownBg==='Disabled'">
<style type="text/css">
.ui-select-toggle{
    background: grey !important;
  }
</style>

</div>
```

But this doesn't work. By default browser seems to be ignoring and `divs` with `*ngIf` and only the last style overrides the others. Below is the browser interpretation:

[image]
UPDATE: This scenario arose because I'm using `ng-select` dropdown which internally uses class 'ui-select-toggle'over which I don't have any control. So **WEIRD** people downvoting this question, please take a note of that.

This is the code:

```
<div style="min-width: 200px;position: absolute;right: 0">
           <ng-select 
                   [items]="items"
                    (selected)="selected($event)"
                    [active]="selectedItem"
                     (removed)="removed($event)"
                  placeholder="Select a number">
          </ng-select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 9):

You can't dynamically change stylesheet of the document like this. Instead, define classes for possible situations and change the toggle's class.

Try something like this:

```
.ui-select-toggle             { /* whatever */ }
.ui-select-toggle.suspended   { background: red; }
.ui-select-toggle.active      { background: green; }
```

And then change class of the toggle:

```
<div 
    class="ui-select-toggle" 
    [class.suspended]="dropDownBg==='Suspended'"
    [class.active]="dropDownBg==='Active'"
>
</div>
```

An element can have several CSS classes, so that you can define common properties in main class (ui-select-toggle) and extra properties specific for each state in the secondary class.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do that. I'm using ng-select which uses this class  
ui-select-toggle internally. I want to modify this class properties based on condition.

Comment: Can you change wrapper's class of something around of the ng-select? If so, you can use the same technique, only to parent element:  .suspended .ui-select-toggle { background: red; } etc. And then change the class of angular component inside:  <div 
    [class.suspended]="dropDownBg==='Suspended'"
    [class.active]="dropDownBg==='Active'"
>  <!-- ng select or whatever you need can go here -->
</div>

Comment: <div style="min-width: 200px;position: absolute;right: 0">
           <ng-select 
                   [items]="items"
                    (selected)="selected($event)"
                    [active]="selectedItem"
                     (removed)="removed($event)"
                  placeholder="Select a number">
          </ng-select>
        </div>

This is how that looks. Even if I change the wrapper, that doesn't affect .

Answer (score 3):

In your case you must create 3 styles
and you use the directive

```
[NgClass] = "{style1: condition, style2: condition, style3: condition}
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's only one property (here being background), you can do this :

```
<div [style.background]="...">...</div>
```

In your case, it could be :

```
<div [style.background]="dropDownBg === 'Active' ? 'green' : dropDownBg === 'Suspended' ? : red : dropDownBg === 'Disabled' ? 'grey' : 'black'">...</div>
```

With black being your fallback color.